How to add my somewhat unique non-standard experience to U.S. federal resume?
I am applying for a job that requires skill in researching and understanding regulations, statutes, and policies. This happens to be a skill that I am exceptionally skilled in but these skills and related legal skills are not from a class or any job listed on my resume. I obtained what I would call intermediate level skills regarding various aspects of the legal field from growing up the son of a successful attorney and law school professor and working at his firm during the summer during high school and for a couple years after high school (2000-2004) and would now consider my skills to be advanced for a management and program analyst role.
The two major issues that I am having are:

None of the work that I did from 2004-2019 is relevant to the position and I do not feel that adding 5-6 jobs that are not overly dispositive for the job I am applying for would be productive and could be counterproductive.
These are skills that I have used to both file VA disability and vocational rehabilitation claims and successfully appeal improper decisions for both disability and voc rehab that required reasonably high-level legal research and analysis skills and when conducting policy analyses and proposals [1].

Would it be reasonable to briefly summarize in a sentence or two and offer to explain in more detail in an interview?
[1] In case any attorneys are responding and can suggest how to make this resume friendly, I will briefly summarize. For the disability increase claim, I researched 38 CFR Ch 3&4, the associated U.S. Code, and the VA Manual to create a checklist of every element for general eligibility and for each rating and then provided 1-2 pieces of evidence for each element. While that is simple, I feel it is an essential skill. Then for appealing a voc rehab denial I conducted research into the same three sources as well as appellate caselaw. The first step of the appeal process is to request higher level review, but because of covid the VA office was shut down and my case file was not available which meant that I could take my one bite at the apple of higher level review before formal appeals which take years but it would have to be done without seeing what evidence the VA had on file or didn't have.  However, buried in the relevant statutes and regulations was an avenue for a collateral attack because in addition to the main review there is a path called revision where one can request revision of clear and unmistakable errors. Because VA benefits are protected property interests, they are not discretionary and thus the VA was required to approve training to the next higher level to compensate for competitive disadvantage."

So you had a job 2000-2004 where you developed/demonstrated skills that are relevant to the job you are now applying for, but believe it is better to leave that job off your resume? Why?

My concern is more about how to include it most effectively. Like would it be problematic to just skip the irrelevant jobs. My other concern was that adding the jobs from 2004-2019 would make my resume much longer, risking the possibility that they stop reading the resume before getting to the important work experience at the end.

You have a 20 year old dated experience that you didn't use since. It will likely be glossed over no matter what as it has been two decades


Never said I didn’t use it (it’s rather useful in public policy and public administration, which is what I do and why this is a job requirement). 2. I didn’t magically forget what issue spotting, elemental analysis, causation, judicial review, regulatory discretion, etc. are. 3. Your answer does not actually help answer my question. My point of posting this was explicitly to minimize the risk of that happening. Leaving it out means that, on paper, I’m unqualified for a job that I’m more than qualified for.


@JewJitsu11B how did you use in last 20 years that is commercially relevant? Liike, not to trivialise but this sounds like typical basic paralegal work, and that's times a plenty in the job market.

Yes, your assertion that it is "basic paralegal work" is not exactly incorrect. The job is for a management and program analyst position with the U.S. Federal Government, so the ability to research and analyze regulations and case law are useful skills, but it doesn't actually involve the practice of law. As for "commercially relevant", the skills in question are skills that I used in conducting every analytical paper in undergrad and grad school. Most notably, I used these skills to develop a novel framework of analysis for conducting diagnostic/interventionistic analysis of a population. 1/2

@AidaPaul For example, the use of element analysis (a.k.a. component analysis) was a central aspect of the aforementioned framework, a framework I created for my MPA Thesis. One of the reasons for why I did this was because a type of logical inference (abductive inference) used heavily in law (and other fields) is not explicitly or formally utilized in mine. In the interest of brevity, I'll simply note that there's a reason why my thesis advisor's feedback started by noting my heavy use of legalistic thinking and argumentation. I also used it repeatedly to resolve VA benefits issues pro se.

You have multiple serious problems here:

The experience is 20 years old.
You cannot easily articulate how you kept up to date with the skills learned in that experience.
The experience, even if it was fresh, is far from being even uncommon, not to mention rare or in some way heavily sought after. It's effectively what paralegals do, and there are dime a dozen of those, partially because it takes i think 6 weeks in the US to do basic training? I may be wrong on that.
I will also add as someone who've been through law school relatively recently, the way you read, interpret and research law (and file based on it) now is nothing like it was 20 years ago. World has moved on, while reading, attention to details still matter, the rest is down to knowing how to use databases and little else.

I don't know why you hang to that experience so firmly, for me that would be anecdote to mention over a beer. But as you insist the way to bring it up is to get paralegal (re)training. This way you can put the training at the very top of your CV, and when asked about link back to the 20 years ago experience. But be ready for it to be easily dismissed, so you need to be able to explain it briefly and succinctly focusing on how (if at all) it still applies, and how you've kept up to date. Make sure that what you describe cannot be constituted as practicing law, as doing so without proper training is... Not exactly something to brag about.
